# Getting value from a list of objects

Tags: python, list, oop

I try to write a program which will generate me all possible combinations of positions in given range of X and Y. For example: [A1,A2,A3,B1,...] 
As I am new to OOP I have some problem with printing these values. Below is my code:

```
X = ['A','B','C']  
Y = ['1','2','3']

class Combination:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        if (x in X) and (y in Y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        else:
            print "WRONG!!"

    def __str__ (self):
        return x+y

class Position:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xy = []
        for i in X:
            for j in Y:
                self.xy.append(Combination(i,j))
    def __str__(self):
        return "List contains: " + str(self.xy)

P1 = Position()
print P1
```

My result is:

```
List contains: [<__main__.Combination object>, <__main__.Combination object>,....
```

As I mentioned, I would like to see something like that:
[A1,A2,A3,B1,...]
If I change line:

```
 self.xy.append(Combination(i,j))
```

to:

```
 self.xy.append(i,j)
```

It works fine but I want to use class Combination there.

Does anyone know how to do it? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Combinations` class, you need to define `__repr__` method, instead of `__str__` like this

```
def __repr__ (self):
    return self.x+self.y
```

with this change, the output is

```
List contains: [A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :) I am new to OOP and I didn't know about __repr__ only __str__. You really saved me because I spent many hours to figure it out other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your Combination `__str__` method needs improving. Firstly, I suspect it should be `__repr__` and secondly it needs `self.x + self.y`